# Problem with overloaded methods in F#

Tags: f#

Why code like this doesn't compile?

```
type MyType() =
    static member myMember (f,(g,h)) = g
    static member myMember (a,(b,c,d)) = MyType.myMember(a,(b,c))
    static member myMember (a,(b,c,d,e)) = MyType.myMember(a,(b,c))
```

It says: ... The tuples have differing lengths of 2 and 4

It is a bug?

Comment: It indeed looks like a bug to me. Your last member tries calling the second member, even though it should call the first one. Am I missing some point as well?

Comment: I suppose it's beside the point, but I'm curious why you would want to do this.

Comment: I don't. It's the second time I find this "bug" while coding overloaded functions that calls each others. The code I published it's just a simplified example to reflect just the "bug". In a real world situation it happens sometimes you define a function that does something with one parameter, but if you supply 2 it does the same as with one plus something else maybe more specific with the second, and so on.

Comment: Don't get me wrong. I already have some workarounds calling helper functions, but my question it's just if this is a bug or there is something wrong in the code.

Comment: Looks like a bug to me, too. Another workaround idea: F# also has optional parameters, in case you were unaware of the feature. However, that will not work in nested tuples.

Comment: It is inconsistent too. If you swap the last two lines, whatever is the last line won't compile. But just one overloaded method works fine, whichever one you choose. I assume it has something to do with the arity of the overload, you can see Don Syme's reply to a similar post here: http://cs.hubfs.net/forums/thread/1635.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if it's a bug, but generally speaking type inference in the presence of multiple overloads is hard to do well.  Your best bet is to add some type annotations:

```
type MyType() =
  static member myMember<'a,'b,'c> (f:'a,(g:'b,h:'c)) = g
  static member myMember (a,(b,c,d)) = MyType.myMember<_,_,_>(a,(b,c))
  static member myMember (a,(b,c,d,e)) = MyType.myMember<_,_,_>(a,(b,c))
```